# UML no fields (state) in class

Tags: uml, modeling

If my class (interface) has no fields, should I leave white space to make it obvious that there is to state?

With whitespace:
[image: UML with whitespace]

No whitespace:
[image: UML without whitespace]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use with whitespace. I've seen some examples on the web like this (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/). In Figure 10, The Person interface has no methods, but the space to put methods is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it both ways. Compartments can be set ad libitum. Use whatever fits your taste best. You should however setup modeling rules that constraint the use of compartments to whatever you think might be the best. The UML spec e.g. uses this on p. 16:

> Within such a diagram, all of the metaclasses described in that clause are depicted with their attribute compartments, while metaclasses whose definition appears in another clause are depicted with just their headers and no compartments.

And some more examples on pp. 193.

P.S. I have just checked what EA shows in case and it will not show an empty compartment but completely suppress it.